# Characteristic function converges pointwise to 0 - Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

I have seen this claim on Winston Ou Real Analysis Lecture on youtube but he does not really explain how to get this conclusion

$f_n =  \chi_{[n,n +1)}$ converges pointwise to 0.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand how this function is defined and what you are trying to show?

Comment: I understand that this function has the value 1 if x is between [n, n+1] and 0 otherwise, he is claiming that for any x of the function the distance between f(x) and 0 is arbitrarily small when n goes to infinity. I would not think that this is true because the distance needs to be 1 and not arbitrarily small when x in [n, n+1].

Comment: I do know that somehow this idea of the distance needing to be one does not make sense because of his claim, but I do not know why.

Comment: Remember that in the definition of pointwise convergence, epsilon *and* x can be fixed at the start of your proof. This should help

Answer (score 2):

$f_n(x) = 0$ if $n > x$, so the limit as $n \to \infty$ is $0$.